# Can I get the Windows 7 repair CD for free?

Tags: windows-7, system-repair-disc

I messed up my Windows 7 and I need to run repair, but I don't have the CD. So, maybe it's possible to get just repair thing for free and mount it in USB and fix the Windows?

Comment: Who is the System manufacturer?  They may have restore media available.

Comment: @DaveM: You mean Dell?

Comment: Yes If that is who made the system. They will offer a restore DVD.  There will be a small charge.

Comment: Are you sure your Dell doesn't have a factory restore partition on it?

Comment: How much space do you have on the disk? If you need to keep the data, the first thing you'll want to do it back it up. Booting with a liveUSB (parted magic would be good for what you're about to do), and partition the disk. Move all the data you need backed up to the new, empty partition. From there you can consider restoring the partition, or reinstalling from scratch.

Comment: Unfortunately many manufacturers are not including installation/recovery CDs with their computers these days.  This is a major inconvenience for users, and I suggest everyone who has experienced this write a complaint to their vendor about it.  When we buy software, the very minimal cost for an installation/restore CD/DVD really should be included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the maker is Dell as indicated, they likely will offer a restore CD.  That will restore the system to the condition it was when shipped.  It will not be a Windows 7 disk that you can use for a repair. A call to  support or use online chat for more info.

There will be a fee for the disk and shipping.

If your main concern is the data, you can possibly move the disk to another system in an external case or as a second drive and recover.  You can also can use a bootable disk as noted by @Rob and recover in place.

That would let you do a  recovery with a Dell recovery disk after the data is safe

Comment: well, I need repair, I need those files.

Comment: If the system has a valid Windows 7 COA sticker atttached, you could use someone elses Windows 7 DVD.  This has worked for me in some cases.  Some WIN  7 DVD/CD may not accept your key.  It depends on the version OEM, Retail, Enterprise, etc.

Comment: Please explain the downvote

Comment: Are you sure the Dell CD isn't similar to a regular Windows CD? It might offer a recovery console and repair.  I think it likely that I used a Dell XP CD and it looked the same except it forced you to use the Dell Serial not a windows serial, so I guess they do it for Windows 7. And that it has a repair. They did an OS CD and a drivers CD. They might do a full restoration CD now, but perhaps also the plain OS CD and Drivers CD.

Answer (score 2):

Ask around to see if anyone you know has a Windows 7 install CD. As long as it's the same version that your CD key is for, it will work for a repair install (or fresh install). The back of your case should have a sticker with the CD key and version on it.